# Bayesian bandits with delayed rewards

Tags: bayesian, optimization

I looked into the topic of bayesian bandits in order to create a simple testing tool for headline optimizations. UCB1 seemed easy enough until I discovered that there is probably a problem with the delayed rewards in the real life setup. I am in no way a mathematician. Maybe anyone could point me in the right direction on how to handle this?

Thanks
Valentin

Comment: Velcome to our site!

Comment: What kind of problem? Meaning measurement error?

Comment: @ssdecontrol As far as I know UCB1 expects immediate feedback befor the next prediction is made. On a homepage thats usually not the case. People might decide not click or take several minutes to click. Meanwhile other people come and there are new predictions to be made.

Comment: I'm of no help then, but this might be: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/226206909_One-armed_bandit_models_with_continuous_and_delayed_responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conservative approach is to not update your pulls until after some period of time.  This requires that you store each outstanding pull as a separate record and run a batch job to update the arms.

Otherwise, you just update your pulls immediately.  When you're starting out, this will penalize winning bandits more than it should, but once the system is mature and the number of historical pulls is much greater than the number of outstanding pulls, then this error will shrink away.